# How to center UITextField text while typing?

Tags: swift, swift4

When entering more than 2 characters, the text field is no longer centered, only after have finished typing will text become centered in the text field. How can I continuously make the text centered?

[While typing in text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqC8n.png)

[After finished typing in text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkDl6.png)

Comment: are you sure you have set the `alignment` as center in storyboard?

Comment: can you show the `constraints` and `alignment` configured in `storyboard` for `textField`?

Comment: @Kamran It's centered in the storyboard. https://i.imgur.com/nXc5tVg.png

Comment: Same problem here. @NickM have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the text alignment to Center using StoryBoard:

[image]

**This will make your text to be center forcefully:**

You can also set in progrmmatically

```
textField.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. While TYPING, it does not center. A simple alignment in the storyboard, doesn't work.

Comment: @NickM I guess there is some mistake with constraints, cause by setting it to centre it worked for me.